# No Grub Bootloader after installing any linux distribution

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

Recently, I tried a fresh install of Ubuntu 19.10. The installation was completed successfully, but after reboot it directly boots in Windows. While installing Ubuntu, I clearly saw, that GRUB was successfully installed but after reboot no change occurred.

I also tried Ubuntu 19.04, Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, Kali Linux, but the problem is same. My partitions were root, swap, reserved BIOS. I have already tried reinstalling GRUB from Live CD, bootrepair and other stuff but problem is same. I even tried, adding EFI entry from Windows CMD, but laptop upon booting shows: *No boot media* and restarts infinitely.

Comment: If you have a bios_grub partition that is a BIOS(UEFI - CSM) boot on gpt partitioned drive. If you have an ESP - efi system partition (FAT32) that would be UEFI boot. You may need to either install in UEFI boot mode, or reset system to boot in the old BIOS/CSM mode. Shows installer with screen shots. Both BIOS purple accessibility screen & UEFI black grub menu screen
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

Answer (score 0):

go through bad way use live ubuntu and **copy-paste** **grub files** from live ubuntu to ubuntu.

> copy paste using terminal with root user

Comment: Right now i have Kali Linux installed and don't know how and which file to copy and paste. Moreover, i guess grub is installed but is not executing.

Comment: actually above answer considered as on **ubuntu only** and why not you try this only using ubuntu its mostly applicable for that.